# Unable to get ID for a asp:dropdownlist which gets populated dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an unbound list that gets populated.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" style="margin-left: 81px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged"   
    CssClass="styled-select">
</asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlManagerName"  runat="server" Height="22px" 
    style="margin-left: 08px; width:auto;" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

and a javascript that runs to get the id on a button click

```
function validateDynamic() {

    var getState = document.getElementById('<%=ddlState.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;
    var getManager = document.getElementById('<%=ddlManagerName.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;
    if(getState == 0)
    { 
        alert("State is a required field !");

    }

    if(getManager == 0)
    { 
        alert("Manager Name is a required field !");

    }

    return false;
}
```

I have tried most using the following  from view source

name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlState" id="MainContent_ddlState"  both name and id and all i get is object undefined.

Here is the button code that gets calls the function

```
  <asp:Button id="btnSaveTM" runat="server" Text="Add Team Member" class="btn"   onmouseover="this.className='btn btnhov'"
   onmouseout="this.className='btn'" style=" Height:34px" OnClientClick="validateDynamic();"
    onclick="btnSaveTM_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CausesValidation="true"   />
```

and when I debug, I get getState and manager as undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that document.getElementById('<%=ddlState.ClientID %>') actually getting the element?

Comment: Are both of your elements visible?

Comment: You need to get the id or selected value.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the selected value of DropdownList:

```
var getState = (document.getElementById('<%= ddlState.ClientID %>')  
                     .options[document.getElementById("<%=ddlState.ClientID%>") 
                     .selectedIndex].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the sourcecode returned by the server? Does the ID in the script match the ID of the rendered element? Also code nuggets like `<%=ddlState.ClientID %>` don't work in an external script file. To get them to work you have to embed the script on the page. They only work with .aspx files.
Also you could try to get the element on the console (like Chrome DevTools). If you the right element is returned you can compare it with the line in your script.